# Copy Custom font with with Font Style and Font Size

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uipasteboard

It's paste simple text when I copy text with below code.

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, tvTexta.attributedText!.length)
            let rtfData = try! tvTexta.attributedText!.data(from: range,
                                                            documentAttributes: [ NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf])

            UIPasteboard.general.items = [
                [ kUTTypePlainText as String : tvTexta.text! ],
                [ kUTTypeRTF as String : rtfData ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you are adding the data to the pasteboard. What you are doing is adding **multiple items** to the pasteboard, and what you actually *want* to do is add **multiple representations of the same item**:

```
UIPasteboard.general.items = [[
    kUTTypePlainText as String : tvTexta.text!,
    kUTTypeRTF as String : rtfData 
]]
```